# Emergencies and other imminent hazard tags should tell users to call appropriate services rather than look for an answer on the internet

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I stumbled upon [this question](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/676/so-i-created-the-emergency-tag-today?cb=1) and thought that it would be rather cool to tell users to act now if something bad is due to happen if no action is taken quickly, and propose a few methods of getting medical aid.

Some social networks detect keywords in posts that may refer to suicide and will show a message proposing to get some help (suicide prevention hotline phone numbers, etc). SE has several sites where people could think to post a question about severe health concerns. I suppose there should be a system that detects words like "emergency" and whatnot (*I'm really bad at designing such systems, so I wouldn't know*) and show a message with links and phone numbers of medical institutions, veterinary clinics and such.

I know it may sound stupid how some people think of posting about their dangerous situation on the internet first, but it's not like it hasn't happened before.

Comment: Sorry for terrible phrasing. Feel free to turn this into a comprehensible proposition.

Comment: `Some social networks...` but Stack Exchange is not a social network

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think the social networks were just mentioned as an example of some large sites that do it.

Comment: @3ventic Probably but still, anything that makes SE more like a social network pushes us towards being consider a social network.

Comment: This is exactly why I argued against allowing veterinary advice questions on pets.se to begin with.

Comment: A very sensible argument if you ask me @Wooble. Even the whole [emergency] tag sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I'm not saying that the "emergency" tag is fine, I'm saying it could be a sure indicator that the poster is in trouble and needs help. As I said, forgive my poor phrasing.

Comment: @AlienArrays Well, we're not really talking SO here. But that was one of the points I was trying to make indeed. Anything will be an emergency. And I don't think sites should get themselves involved in things that are true emergencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes down to it "get immediate attention" only is applicable on sites that deal with living things, which pretty much confines us to Pets.SE and Parenting.SE.  Unless I am missing a site, an "emergency" on any other site doesn't constitute a real emergency.

[Bart's point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218350/182513) about being impractical is spot on.  There is little we can do to direct most users to appropriate help.  Frankly, if we try to offer that level of help and the info is incorrect or out-of-date, that might open Stack Exchange to possible liability for not providing up to date information.

At most, I think a general warning on the most affected sites (Pets & Parenting) when asking a question indicating that questions of an emergency nature should be directed to appropriate medical authorities would be sufficient without specialized tags or popups when using specific tags.

Comment: You're missing Biology.SE. It covers human stuff and they have a "medical advice" close reason.

Comment: IMO general warning could be quite the thing.

Comment: There's also Interpersonal.SE that often get questions related to mental health issues and disorders and that could such warning.

Answer (score 12):

Just leave a comment.

> I suppose there should be a system that detects words like "emergency" and whatnot (I'm really bad at designing such systems, so I wouldn't know)

Actually detecting what messages might indicate that something requires urgent intervention is very non-trivial, even more so when you want to prevent a lot of false positives. A couple of keywords just won't do it. Especially when discussing topics related to (mental) health.

> and show a message with links and phone numbers of medical institutions, veterinary clinics and such.

Stack Exchange is far too international for that to work. If you need to go see a vet or a doctor, you better go to the nearest one available. You wouldn't want to be presented with some US hotline when you're somewhere in Australia. And you might not even find a hotline useful when what you really need is your nearest vet/doctor now.

In the comments you say

> I was thinking that if the poster tries to use tag emergency, it might be enough to consider it a real threat.

That is not what tags are for though. You are now creating a tag that is just meant to say "Don't ask this here". That's not a good classifier at all. If you disallow questions that have that tag, people will ask their questions without it. If you want to have more attention for questions with that tag, everybody will use it.

Though I do not participate on such sites, I do understand that it's difficult to deal with cases of immediate urgency for beings you care for. Cases involving immediate danger to animal or human lives are always difficult. But such communities should realize that they are a ultimately a Q&A, not an emergency hotline. It is not their responsibility. At most they should make it very clear up front (if they don't do so already on About pages and the like) that they are never a substitute for professional help, nor that they can guarantee an accurate answer at all or within any time frame.

In short, whenever you see something that requires immediate intervention, leave a comment telling the user to go look for help now. And we don't really need an automated system for that.

Comment: I was thinking that if the poster tries to use tag `emergency`, it might be enough to consider it a real threat. So, even though such a tag should not be used for real questions, the site could still point out to the user that it's time to go to a corresponding facility. Not necessarily create a complex system that'd analyze the post and what you mentioned.

Comment: Also, the user over at the pets meta are concerned that OP might not get such a comment in time. This is why I thought about solving this at the time of posting.

Comment: Nah, let's not start introducing tags just so we can say "you shouldn't really be asking this here". That is not what tags are for. As for not getting messages in time, I would suggest to the community that they stop worrying about that. We're dealing with Q&A's. We're not emergency hotlines and it's not our responsibility. (No matter how difficult it might be to accept that distinction, when your gut instinct is to care. Be it for animal or human life)